# PHP array multisort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

I am attempting to sort an array based off the key, "dispatched". However, it is not working. Does anyone have any pointers to  get this code working? Thanks:

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wcccanumber] => 130700203
            [call] => SEIZURES
            [address] => 221 S PINE ST
            [county] => C
            [station] => CNB
            [department] => CANBY FIRE DISTRICT #62
            [units] => E61, M62
            [dispatched] => 20:43:59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [wcccanumber] => 130700198
            [call] => CARD/RESP ARREST
            [address] => 40781 HWY 26
            [county] => C
            [station] => SAN
            [department] => SANDY FIRE DISTRICT #72
            [units] => 3709, CH37, M1, M272, R71
            [dispatched] => 19:33:27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wcccanumber] => 130700337
            [call] => TRAUMA C1
            [address] => 16500 SW CENTURY DR
            [county] => W
            [station] => SHW
            [department] => TUALATIN VALLEY FIRE & RESCUE
            [units] => E33, METWA, MW68
            [dispatched] => 21:40:13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [wcccanumber] => 130700335
            [call] => FALL C1
            [address] => 48437 NW PONGRATZ RD
            [county] => W
            [station] => BUX
            [department] => BANKS FIRE DISTRICT #13
            [units] => E14, METWA, MW57, R13
            [dispatched] => 21:07:48
        )

)
```

Code:

```
public function sortActiveCalls () 
{
    foreach ($this->getActiveCalls() as $key => $val) {
           $time[$key] = $val['dispatched'];
    }

    array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $this->getActiveCalls());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier just to use usort

```
 usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
       return strtotime($a["dispatched"]) - strtotime($b["dispatched"]);
 });
```

For your case you would reimplement your `sortActiveCalls` method as

```
public function sortActiveCalls(){
     $data = $this->getActiveCalls();
     usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
       return strtotime($a["dispatched"]) - strtotime($b["dispatched"]);
     });
     return $data;
}
```

Not this will only work in php 5.3 and up

If you are using an older version of php you will have to define a separate function to do the sort like

```
if (!function_exists("sortByDispatched")){
  function sortByDispatched($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a["dispatched"]) - strtotime($b["dispatched"]);
  }
}
usort($array, "sortByDispatched");
```

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: posted a solution that will work for older versions of php as well.

Comment: Yeah which each method I get an undefined variable a and b.

Comment: Put an "in the wild" example for you in the answer that should show how the code should be used.

Comment: Yeah, I just formatted a little different and got it working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In additional to what Orangepill said, if you are using 5.2 or older, you can use the [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to create an anonymous (lambda-style) function instead. For example,

```
usort($array, create_function( '$a,$b', 
'return strtotime($a["dispatched"]) - strtotime($b["dispatched"]);'));
```