# Sort array by custom date time

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I have next array:

```
Array ( 
[15709] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15709 
  [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 00:30:00 
  [program_info] => Х/ф "Стелла" ) 
[15710] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15710 [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 02:20:00 
  [program_info] => Х/ф "Часы доблести" ) 
[15711] => stdClass Object ( 
  [pid] => 15711 
  [channel_ID] => 51 
  [date] => 2016-03-21 06:15:00 
  [program_info] => Фильм-концерт "Хичкок. Концерт в магазине" 
) )
```

I need sort him by field `[date]`, should first go to the elements starting from the specified time 05:00:00, result must be somthing like this:

```
Array ( 
    [15711] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15711 
      [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 06:15:00 
      [program_info] => Фильм-концерт "Хичкок. Концерт в магазине" )
    [15709] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15709 
      [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 00:30:00 
      [program_info] => Х/ф "Стелла")
    [15710] => stdClass Object ( 
      [pid] => 15710 [channel_ID] => 51 
      [date] => 2016-03-21 02:20:00 
      [program_info] => Х/ф "Часы доблести"
    ) )
```

Comment: actually first array is sorted by date, second one is not. or I miss something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439905/php-array-multisort look this question. you question is dublicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort multi-dimensional array by specific key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022289/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-specific-key)

Comment: use `usort`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: I need sort from 05:00:00 time, from 05:00 to 04:59

Comment: have you tried `usort` yet? Show what you have tried.

Comment: your question doesnt make sense. your expected result is not sorted by date.

Comment: result must sort by custom date time

Comment: @CodeGodie, I need sort from 05:00 to 04:59, somthing like this:
`array('05:00','06:00','07:00','12:00','14:00','16:00','22:00','23:00','02:00','04:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
uasort($myarray, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? -1 : 1;
})
```

Comment: I need sort from 05:00 to 04:59, somthing like this:
`array('05:00','06:00','07:00','12:00','14:00','16:00','22:00','23:00','02:00','04:00')`

Comment: You can explode the date in the function and compare the time only